# memorize a value of a dictionary

Tags: python, function, dictionary, addition, updates

I'm a bit of a newbie in Python but is it possible to do the following?
I want to create a dictionary,test_tube, that shows what liquid is in it and the quantity of it. With the function add_liquid I want to add a new liquid or more of the previously used liquid to the test tube, without the use of defaultdicts.

```
Def add_liquid(test_tube,liquid,milliliters=0):
     test_tube[liquid] = milliters
     return test_tube 
     #update of previous test tube and memorize new test tube           

>>>add_liquid(test_tube,'water',10) 
{'water':10}
>>>more_water=add_liquid(test_tube,'water',5)
>>>more_water
{'water':15}
>>>add_liquid(test_tube,'ethanol',1)
{'ethanol':1, 'water':15}
```

Python must somehow memorize what the previously quantity of liquid was in the test_tube.
Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: Do you mean that you want to be able to know what the previous value of `test_tube` is? Or which liquid was previously added?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why don't you want to use `defaultdict`? Would it be reasonable to implement your own `defaultdict`-like class?

Comment: If you don't like defaultdict, you can use `from collections import Counter` if all you are doing is doing counts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you just need to check if the liquid is already in there, and if so, add the amounts.

```
if liquid in test_tube:
    test_tube[liquid] += milliliters
else: 
    test_tube[liquid] = milliliters
```

Another way to formulate this is to set the value to the sum of the current value or 0 of there is no, and milliliters:

```
test_tube[liquid] = test_tube.get(liquid, 0) + milliliters
```

Note that you need to either define your function so that it modifies the dictionary that you pass in (and then you shouldn't really return anything), or that it returns a modified copy of it.

Comment: @user1830011 Please accept the answer by clicking on the left if you're satisfied. :)

Answer (score 2):

You want to store test_tube as a variable which you pass to add_liquid(). Also, you want it to add to the liquid value if it already exists.

```
def add_liquid(test_tube,liquid,milliliters=0):
    test_tube[liquid] = test_tube.setdefault(liquid, 0) + milliters
    return test_tube

test_tube = add_liquid(test_tube,'water',10)
more_water = add_liquid(test_tube,'water',5)
```

etc.

Comment: I think that instead of `setdefault(liquid, 0)` you should use `get(liquid, 0)`; there's no point in setting a key, returning its value and then setting it again.

Answer (score 1):

you'll want something like:

```
if liquid not in test_tube.keys():
    test_tube.update({liquid:milliliters})
else:
    test_tube[liquid] += milliliters
```

Comment: There's no need for `keys()` or `update({})`. `liquid in test_tube` already checks against the keys, and `test_tube[liquid] = milliliters` is a clearer way to add a new key and value.

Answer (score 0):

If you are only doing counts, and you don't like `defaultdict()`, you can use the `Counter()` object from collections:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> test_tube = Counter()
>>> test_tube["water"] = 10
>>>
>>> # more water
>>> test_tube["water"] += 5
>>> test_tube["water"]
15
>>> test_tube["ethanol"] = 1
>>> test_tube
Counter({'water': 15, 'ethanol': 1})
>>>
```